# animated svg loading icon until image loaded

Tags: javascript, css, svg-animate

I am trying to achieve the behavior with CSS (or js if needed) for a **svg icon**. The structure of my HTML is something like this:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="image.jpg" class="img load">
</picture>
```

I found this [simple CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742508/show-loading-gif-while-image-is-loading/29742754):

```
.load {
  background: transparent url('loading-icon.svg') no-repeat center;
}
```

But, I need spin effect on the icon. I can't use gif image as the original icon is custom icon. So, I needed to put the [icon in pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949455/css3-css-spinning-background-image):

```
picture:before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url('loading-icon.svg');
  /* top: 50%; */
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Now, to be honest, I am not sure I have implemented it correctly or not as I can't see the icon loading. I saw icon loading when I used `png` image to test; but after using `svg` image, I can't see it loading. Can you please take a look and let me know if there are any issues or need any improvements?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/f5qvop6L/46/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you animate a svg "background-image"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927170/can-you-animate-a-svg-background-image)

Comment: Actually, after using solution of @Hancel, my code is working now. But, I am confused why png icon worked without this css while svg icon failed to work without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `background-size: 100%;` in `picture:before`. because your loading picture is bigger than box size.

Comment: Thanks, after using it, it seems that the demo is working now. When I used png image, it worked without this background-size property; but after using SVG image, it didn't work without this css. Any idea why has this happened?

Comment: The size of PNG and SVG is the same?

Comment: No, there was a slight difference.